# Convert NSInlineData to Nstring in ios

Tags: ios

i am trying to get a substring from a parent string. parent string is mac address of device available in a dictionary. But when i try to convert it it si giving me error as below "[_NSInlineData substringFromIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance".

I just want to remove some of the chars from the parent string (here it is mac address like "<0001ui3 234563>" ) and get "ui3 234563".

```
   // This is my nsdictionary.
  advertisementdata = {     kCBAdvDataIsConnectable = 1;     kCBAdvDataLocalName = "test123";     kCBAdvDataManufacturerData = <00029r21 6y051rt2>;     kCBAdvDataServiceUUIDs =     (         FFF0     );     kCBAdvDataTxPowerLevel = 0; }

 // I want 9r216y051rt from kCBAdvDataManufacturerData;
 NSString *str2;


 str2=[advertisementData objectForKey:@"kCBAdvDataManufacturerData"];

 NSString *str3;
 str3=[str2 substringFromIndex:5];

 // here I do not get the required 12 character string from str2 string.

 get NSInlinedata error for all NSString method.
```

Thanks,

Comment: Update your question with your relevant code.

Comment: What you're trying to reference is not an NSString but rather an NSData object.

Comment: I don't think this is the code that gives the error.

Comment: Show the real code for how `data2` is initialized.

Comment: And show us the exception stack trace.

Comment: Please check my new code for this. I am getting empty value in variable "macstring" with this new code.

Comment: `data2` contains data and that data is not an encoded string. What are you actually trying to do with the data in `data2`? Where did that data come from?

Comment: I edited the code to my first written code. Please check.

Answer (score 2):

Note that iOS CoreBlueTooth advertisementData is binary NSData:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBCentralManagerDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Advertisement_Data_Retrieval_Keys

Documentation clearly states:

```
CBAdvertisementDataManufacturerDataKey
A NSData object containing the manufacturer data of a peripheral.
```

BTW, when you have a NSDictionary value type NSData*, you get the error by casting this NSData into a NSString*

// this is a  bug!

> NSString* str2=[advertisementData objectForKey:@"kCBAdvDataManufacturerData"];

To inspect the dictionary value try

```
NSData* advData = [advertisementData objectForKey:@"kCBAdvDataManufacturerData"];
```

Unfortunately, since this is binary, you need to interpret it according to the peripheral manufacturer data documentation. There is no easy way to transform this into a NSString*

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have an NSData object, and you're trying to use an NSString method to access it.  You can convert your NSData object using the call`initWithData: encoding:`
Then apply the substringFromIndex call to your new NSString.

Comment: Yes, i tried that (please check my new code) , but in my variable "macaddress" is giving empty.

Comment: In your code above, you have kCBAdvDataManufacturerData = <00029r21 6y051rt2>,  it should be kCBAdvDataManufacturerData = @"<00029r21 6y051rt2>"

Comment: I am not creating it. I printed what i saw in console. Its actually coming from search functionality of Hardware Bluetooth devices. I have lots of them.

Comment: OK, let's consider that it's NSData.  In that case, change NSString *str2; to NSData * str2;  Then change NSString * str3;  to NSString * str3 = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: str2 encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];  Then do NSString * str4 = [str3 substringFromIndex:5]; Does that make it work?

Answer (score 0):

The point that you have NSInlineData and what you need is hexadecimal representation of data object.

First step should be to get a hexadecimal representation of data object's content in property list format.

```
 NSData *datakCBAdvDataManufacturerData = [advertisementData valueForKey:@"kCBAdvDataManufacturerData"];
 NSString *strmanufacturerData      = datakCBAdvDataManufacturerData.description;
 NSString *ChkStr = [strmanufacturerData substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(10, 8)];//depends upon your requirement.
 NSLog(@"%@",ChkStr);

 unsigned int outVal;
 NSScanner* scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:ChkStr];
 [scanner scanHexInt:&outVal];
 NSLog(@"%@",outVal);
```

This outVal variable will contain value what you need.