# Is there a way to get the value of advertisementData in a variable

Tags: swift, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to get the value of `advertisementData[CBAdvertisementDataManufacturerDataKey]` to do an operation on it. What I need to do ?

I have already tried some solutions found on this forum like : [Convert NSInlineData to Nstring in ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26636204/convert-nsinlinedata-to-nstring-in-ios) but this is in objective-c. I have converted it to swift but it didn't work

```swift
let manufacturerdata = advertisementData["kCBAdvDataManufacturerData"] as! NSData
print("value : \(manufacturerdata)")
let manufacturerdatastr = String(data: manufacturerdata as Data, encoding: .utf8)
print("data string  : \(manufacturerdatastr)")
```

I expect the value of `manufacturerdata` but the actual output is `nil`

Comment: It's not a UTF8 String, it's not a "word/sentence". If you want the same output, you might want that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39075043/how-to-convert-data-to-hex-string-in-swift Also, use `advertisementData[CBAdvertisementDataManufacturerDataKey]` instead of `advertisementData["kCBAdvDataManufacturerData"]`.

Comment: WHat if you use `CBAdvertisementDataManufacturerDataKey` instead of `kCBAdvDataManufacturerData`?

Comment: @Larme the problem is that I can print the value of  'advertisementData[CBAdvertisementDataManufacturerDataKey]' but I can't get the value of it in a variable

Comment: @KirilS. I have tried both of CBAdvertisementDataManufacturerDataKey and "CBAdvertisementDataManufacturerDataKey" but it doesn't change anything

Comment: Using `advertisementData[CBAdvertisementDataManufacturerDataKey]`doesn't fix your issue. It's a safer way to retrieve the value. As I said, the value is not UTF8 String valid, so you'll get nil doing `String(data: manufacturerdata as Data, encoding: .utf8)`. Question is seeing the output: `print("value : \(manufacturerdata)")`, what do you want? Did you look at the linked question?

Comment: @Larme what I wanted to do is to get the value in advertisementData[CBAdvertisementDataManufacturerDataKey]  for example : "kCBAdvDataManufacturerData": <0fb2c231>  I just wanted to get 0fb2c231 converted to decimal in a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution for my problem :

```
adData = advertisementData[CBAdvertisementDataManufacturerDataKey]
            let data : NSData = adData as! NSData
            var str1 : String = data.description
            str1 = str1.replacingOccurrences(of: "<", with: "")
            str1 = str1.replacingOccurrences(of: ">", with: "")
            if let value = Int(str1, radix: 16) {
                print(value)
                DataInt=value
            }
```

So I can get the value of advertisementData[CBAdvertisementDataManufacturerDataKey] with type int in decimal in the variable DataInt.

Hope it will be helpfull for you